# Zend_valdiate_alpha combined with special characters

Tags: zend-validate

Zend_valdiate_alpha combined with special characters

Need to combine An alphanumeric character or underscore with string .
for example : need to add control for City name with

not necessary with zend_alpha it can be another way

any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. I need to allow commas, alphas, and whitespaces. The most simple solution, I can think of, is to define callback validation function like this:

```
$myValidator = new Zend_Validate_Callback(function($value) {
    $value = preg_replace('/,/', '', $value);
    $alphaValidator = new Zend_Validate_Alpha(array('allowWhiteSpace' => true));
    if ($alphaValidator->isValid($value)) return true;
    return false;
});
```

And using it like this:

```
if ($myValidator->isValid($input)) {
    // input valid
} else {
    // input invalid
}
```

I know this is old but perhaps it can help somebody and I would be interested if there is a simpler solution.